# Checkbox to approve entry on Google sheets and trigger an approval email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently im having a prompt window popup that collects the S. No of the entry and then approves that entry and sends out an approval email. Instead of this, i wanna have a check box that one checks to approve the entry and a function is triggered

```
function function1() {
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx").getSheetByName("payments");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.prompt('Please enter the S. No of the entry you want to approve', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var sno = result.getResponseText();

  for (var i=1; i<=100 ; i++)
  {
    Logger.log(sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue());
    if(sno == sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue())
    {
      var index = i;
    }

  }
  Logger.log(index);
  var invitem = sheet.getRange(index,5).getValue();
  var invdesc = sheet.getRange(index,6).getValue();
  var reqby = sheet.getRange(index,3).getValue();
  var amount = sheet.getRange(index,8).getValue();
  
  if (button == ui.Button.OK)
  {
    var subject = 'Payment release request approved';
    var body = '<p>Hello</p> <p>This particular payment release is approved from my end</p> <p>Invoice Item: '+ invitem +'</p> <p>Description: '+ invdesc +'</p> <p>Requested By: '+reqby+'&nbsp;</p> <p>Requested By: '+amount+'&nbsp;</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p><em>This is an automated email triggerred post approval</em></p>'
    var email= 'finance@xxxx.xxx';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "Requires HTML", {
        htmlBody: body})

    sheet.getRange(index,16).setValue("Approved").setBackground('#008000');
  }
}
```

Comment: Well how is it going?

Comment: Im having a hard time here. When i trigger the checkbox, the function runs but i still have to enter the row index manually through the dialog box to get all the data from the row.

Comment: Why not pass e to the function because the row is e.range.rowStart

Comment: This worked Splendidly. Thanks. However, the email is being sent from the person who has setup the trigger and not the person who is actually marking the checkbox. Is there anyway i can have the emails that are being sent be from the person who is actually checking the box?

Comment: You can probably get that from Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

Answer (score 0):

#### Okay here's a function and an installable trigger create function

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Your sheet name' && e.range.columnStart == '15' &&  e.value == "TRUE") {
    let snum = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).getValue();
    ApproveAndSendEmail({snum:snum});
  }
}

function createTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyEdit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what needs to be done here. Do i have to setup any triggers?

Comment: You want a better function then provide more details.  Currently it's a simple trigger but I need more details to move beyond that.

Comment: What does collect S. num mean.  Sending an email requires permission so that will necessitate and installable trigger.

Comment: The 1st row is how i am managing rn. I wanna have it like how it is in the 2nd row where there is a check box. https://imgur.com/a/1EafVRu . S. No is the serial number counter im running to index each rows